# Python: create two lists from dict with list of tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

Given this dict:

```
d={0: [(78.65, 89.86),
  (28.0, 23.0),
  (63.43, 9.29),
  (66.47, 55.47),
  (68.0, 4.5),
  (69.5, 59.0),
  (86.26, 1.65),
  (84.2, 56.2),
  (88.0, 18.53),
  (111.0, 40.0)], ...}
```

How do you create two lists, such that `y` takes the first element of each tuple and `x` takes the second, **for each key in d**?

In the example above (only `key=0` is shown) this would be:

```
y=[78.65, 28.0, 63.43, 66.47, 68.0, 69.5, 86.26, 84.2, 88.0, 111.0]
x=[89.86, 23.0, 9.29, 55.47, 4.5, 59.0, 1.65, 56.2, 18.53, 40.0]
```

My attempt is wrong (I tried the `x` list only):

```
for j,v in enumerate(d.values()):    
   x=[v[i[1]] for v in d.values() for i in v]
```

Because:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-bdac6878fe6c> in <module>()
----> 1 x=[v[i[1]] for v in d.values() for i in v]

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not numpy.float64
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: It's not clear to me what should happen if the dictionary contains two elements...

Comment: You mean another list of tuples with `key=1`? In that case, not much, because I want to extract these two lists inside a for loop, so that at each iteration they are something different. Does this answer your question?

Comment: `x=[i[1] for v in d.values() for i in v]` should work for your snippet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your comment correctly, you want to obtain the `x` and `y` coordinates of the tuple list that is associated with key `0`. In that case you can simply use `zip(..)` and `map(..)` to `list`s:

```
y,x = map(list,zip(*d[0]))
```

If you do not want to change `x` and `y` later in your program - immutable lists are basically `tuple`s, you can omit the `map(list,...)`:

```
y,x = zip(*d[0]) # here x and y are tuples (and thus immutable)
```

Mind that if the dictionary contains two elements, like:

```
{0:[(1,4),(2,5)],
 1:[(1,3),(0,2)]}
```

it will **only process the data for the `0` key**. So `y = [1,2]` and `x = [4,5]`.

Comment: Yes, I am. These coordinates are returned in the form `(row, column)`.

Comment: Or, in python 3 it produces iterators, which python unpacks into tuples.

Comment: I like this solution, but what if `y,x = zip(*d[0])` was nested in a for loop to iterate over all keys? Is it enough changing it to `y,x = zip(*d[i])`?

Comment: @CF84: Yes. If you use `for i in d:` it will fetch for each key and obtain `x` and `y` for that key.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
z = [i for v in d.values() for i in v]
x, y = zip(*z)
```

Comment: Why do you construct a new tuple and do not return `i` itself?